# How to render an html string with vuejs inside in Nuxt3 / Vue3

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to write a component in Nuxt3 which will allow me to output a string of html (that contains vue elements).

Here is what I have so far for the component / plugin

`plugins/RenderVueString.js`

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.component('RenderVueString', {
    props: ['html'],
    render(h) {
      return h({
        template: `<div class="RenderVueString">${this.html}</div>`,
      })
    }
  })
})
```

And then in `pages/index.vue`

```
<template>
  <RenderVueString :html="vueHTML" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
 data() {
  return: {
    vueHTML: `<div>This is some vue HTML {{testVar}} <a @click="testFunction()">Run Function</a></div>`,
    testVar: 'Var Value Here'
  }
 },

 methods: {
  testFunction() {
    console.log('test function ran');
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

I get this error: `TypeError: h is not a function`

So I tried adding this to the top of the `plugins/RenderVueString`:

`import {h} from 'vue';`

After that there is no console errors, but nothing renders.

I did try rendering something simple with h like this: `h('div', 'Hello')` and it did output that, but I can't figure out how to output complex html with embedded Vue.

Comment: You will need to render nodes with the following syntax: https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#render-functions-jsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to figure this out by adding the following to `nuxt.config.ts`

```js
hooks: {
  'vite:extendConfig': (config, {isClient, isServer}) => {
    if(isClient) {
      config.resolve.alias.vue = 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler'
    }
  }
},

nitro: {
  commonJS: {
    dynamicRequireTargets: [
      './node_modules/@vue/compiler-core',
      './node_modules/@vue/compiler-dom',
      './node_modules/@vue/compiler-ssr',
      './node_modules/vue/server-renderer',
      './node_modules/vue'
    ]
  },
},

alias: {
  '@vue/compiler-core': '@vue/compiler-core',
  '@vue/compiler-dom': '@vue/compiler-dom',
  '@vue/compiler-ssr': '@vue/compiler-ssr',
  'vue/server-renderer': 'vue/server-renderer',
  'estree-walker': 'estree-walker',
  '@babel/parser': '@babel/parser'
},
```

And then in the `plugins/RenderVueString.js`

```js
import { h, compile } from 'vue';

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.component('RenderVueString', {
    props: ['html'],
    render() {
      return h(compile(this.html), {$emit: this.$emit});
    }
  })
})
```

Allows this on the a template:

```html
<template>
  <RenderVueString :html="vueHTML" @runFunction="testFunction()" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
 data() {
  return: {
    vueHTML: `<div>This is some vue HTML <a @click="$emit('runFunction')">Run Function</a></div>`,
  }
 },

 methods: {
  testFunction() {
    console.log('test function ran');
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

I could also pass in variables as props into the `RenderVueString` component if needed.

This type of functionality is very useful if you're trying to allow some advanced coding from items being pulled from a database / CMS.